# Letter received re abandonment of patent

Tags: application, reinstatement, us20130033156

In reference to the patent: [US 2013/0033156](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130033156)

My name is Lesley Anne Targett, widow of Kenneth Stanley Targett.

I have received a letter from the United States Patent and Trade Mark Office re patent application no: 13/564,752 to say that the application has been abandoned.

The application was made by Kenneth Stanley Targett for inventors Kenneth Stanley Targett and Paul William Brown.

It states that a letter was mailed on 03 September 2014. This letter was not received.
Kenneth Stanley Targett died on the 20th September 2014. He was very ill prior to his death.

Is there any way this application can be reinstated?

Yours Sincerely

Mrs Lesley Anne Targett

Comment: Lesley, This is a community-run website to ask about the patent process or to help find Prior Art on US Patents or Applications. The folks here might be able to provide some general guidance about your options or how to proceed, **but please understand** that we are ***NOT*** affiliated with the Patent Office or any legal entity, so your post is not likely reaching the audience you intend. Otherwise, good luck!

Comment: Move quickly. Reviving an application becomes more difficult the longer it has been abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

You should call a patent lawyer on this.  The rules for reinstating applications should be readily familiar to a patent attorney.

I pulled up the application at http://portal.uspto.gov and it looks like it was deemed abandoned for failure to respond to an office action -- but the office action was a restriction requirement.  This is a very simple type of office action.  It basically says "you're trying to claim more than one invention at once, please pick just one for us to review".  It looks like the inventor was representing himself, which explains why this happened (it would raise real malpractice questions if a lawyer failed to respond to a restriction requirement without specific instructions from a client to that effect).

The next step is for you to call a patent lawyer.  I can refer you to my patent lawyer if you want, but assuming you're from New Hampshire, you might do better finding a local one.  Good luck.

Comment: I would very much like to hear an update on the status of this patent application. This certainly must be a highly unusual situation, and I wonder if the USPTO has any way to accommodate these exceptional cases. I had a quick read through this application, and it looks like it was well-written, from the background to the figures and claims - quite an accomplishment without the assistance of a patent lawyer! I would have added that since Paul William Brown is listed as co-inventor on the application, he may be best able to address the office action (with the assistance of a patent attorney).